# chdir to the location of the .app bundle in C++ macOS application

Tags: c++, macos

I have packaged a macOS binary of an application which loads resources in a folder just outside of the .app bundle. The directory structure looks like

```
Foo/
    Foo.app/
        Contents/
            ...
    resources/
```

I would like to change the working directory of the application to the parent directory `Foo/`, and this is what I have come up with so far.

```
#if defined(APPLE)
    #include "CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h"
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <libgen.h>
#endif


int main() {
#if defined(APPLE)
    // macOS workaround for setting the working directory to the location of the .app
    {
        CFBundleRef bundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef bundleURL = CFBundleCopyBundleURL(bundle);
        char path[PATH_MAX];
        Boolean success = CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(bundleURL, TRUE, (UInt8 *)path, PATH_MAX);
        assert(success);
        CFRelease(bundleURL);

        chdir(dirname(path));
    }
#endif

    ...
}
```

This appears to work on macOS 10.7 and 10.10 (which is all I have to test on), but on 10.12, users have reported that resources are not loading, so I suspect that the above hack no longer works correctly.

Is there a better way of changing to the directory of the .app bundle that is being run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading resources from outside of the app bundle is a security vulnerability. Apple has implemented app translocation (a.k.a. path randomization) in 10.12 to prevent it. Their recommended solution is to ship your app in a signed disk image. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/OSXv10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017145-DontLinkElementID_68):

> Starting in macOS 10.12, you can no longer provide external code or data alongside your code-signed app in a zip archive or unsigned disk image. An app distributed outside the Mac App Store runs from a randomized path when it is launched and so cannot access such external resources. To provide secure execution, code sign your disk image itself using the codesign tool, or distribute your app through the Mac App Store. For more information, see the updated revision to [*macOS Code Signing In Depth*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html).

Comment: Uggghhhh... Thanks for the information though! I'll try the disk image method. With a signed disk image, is it still possible to have the `Foo` directory structure as above?

Comment: Well, the disk image will mount as a volume whose root folder is essentially similar to your Foo folder. It would contain both your app and its neighboring resources. The user would have to copy both together to their local file system together, which is hard to guarantee. You could make the disk image contain an explicit Foo folder to try to encourage the user to copy that as a unit but, again, no guarantee the user will actually do that.

Comment: Another alternative is to ship an installer package rather than a disk image or zip archive. It would install the app and its resources together in their Foo folder, say under /Applications. Finally, have you considered moving those resources into the app bundle, to avoid this whole issue? Why are the resources outside of the app in the first place?

Comment: The software is modular (literally, it's a modular synthesizer simulator http://vcvrack.com/), so the user can add folders (plugins) to the /plugins directory and replace graphics resources at will. The .dmg method wouldn't work because the disk images are read-only as far as I know. I could move the resouces into the bundle, but the user would have to be familiar with messing around with Right Click -> Show Package Contents. The installer could be a good idea, but I'd have to separate the locations of the .app and the /resources and /plugins directories, and the user would have to delete...

Comment: ...the directories on each update of the software. The .app-in-a-folder method is nice because you have one folder per version, but as you mentioned, the security policy of Sierra does not allow that. Not sure what the best method is, since I'm not a macOS user and don't know what macOS users would prefer.

Comment: If you distribute in a disk image, that doesn't mean the user necessarily runs the app from the disk image. Usually, the user is encouraged to copy the app out of the disk image volume to their Applications folder (or wherever they prefer). So, the read-only nature of the disk image should be too restrictive. Sierra doesn't strictly prohibit .app-in-a-folder. It's just that if such an arrangement is delivered by an insecure means (zip archive or unsigned disk image), then it won't work unless/until the user moves the unarchived folder from where it started.

Comment: I think that the default resources should be in the app bundle. Then, the app should also looks somewhere more user-accessible to pick up customizations. For example ~/Library/Application Support/YourAppName/Resources. Since the Finder sort of hides ~/Library, it would be good to have a menu or button in the app to open that folder for the user. If the user needs to be able to delete as well as add resources, then I'd have the app copy the internal resources to the user-accessible dir on first run and then only load them from there so it picks up user modifications.

Comment: Your options are good, but I have found another method and confirmed that it works on 10.12. The application is distributed in a .zip file containing the folder which contains the .app. If the user tries the launch the app on Sierra, it will say "To install Rack, please move the Rack directory to your /Applications folder" and then close. When opened, it checks if it can find resources in the absolute location `/Applications/Rack/`, and if so, sets the cwd to that folder. A signed DMG with a folder inside is the next best method, but I don't agree with the Apple developer license terms.:(

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it, but I haven't tested it yet on all the macOS versions. I hope this helps someone, but I'm not accepting it as an answer until I determine it's the best method.

```
#include <unistd.h> // for chdir
#include <libgen.h> // for dirname
#include <mach-o/dyld.h> // for _NSGetExecutablePath
#include <limits.h> // for PATH_MAX?

char path[PATH_MAX];
uint32_t pathLen = sizeof(path);
int err = _NSGetExecutablePath(path, &pathLen);
assert(!err);

// Switch to the directory of the actual binary
chdir(dirname(path));
// and then go up three directories to get to the folder of the .app bundle
chdir("../../../");
```

Comment: Due to app translocation, this does not work on 10.12 or higher if the quarantine xattr is set. A possible workaround is to assume the location is /Applications/YourAppName and complain via a messagebox and exit if the app is not installed to that location.